# Get upright italic fonts in TeX

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, italic

I can get italic fonts in TeX by `\it` command, but I see there is upright italic font on page 13 of the book **The TeXbook**. How did the author achieve this style?

[image]

See the words

> while the letters in italic type are drawn in a different style.

in the above figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The texbook source is on ctan and you find

```
Notice that two of these faces have an ``^{oblique}'' slope for emphasis:
{\sl ^{Slanted type} is essentially the same as roman, but the letters are
slightly skewed, \it while the letters in ^{italic type} are drawn in a
different style.} \ (You can perhaps best appreciate the difference between
the roman and italic styles by contemplating {\tenu letters that are
in an unslanted italic face.})
```

`manmac.tex` has

```
\font\tenu=cmu10 % unslanted text italic
```

so the following plain tex document

```
\font\tenu=cmu10 % unslanted text italic

Notice that two of these faces have an oblique slope for emphasis:
{\sl Slanted type is essentially the same as roman, but the letters are
slightly skewed, \it while the letters in italic type are drawn in a
different style.} \ (You can perhaps best appreciate the difference between
the roman and italic styles by contemplating {\tenu letters that are
in an unslanted italic face.})

\bye
```

[image]

---

In LaTeX upright italic is the `ui` font shape so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textit{slanted italic} {\fontshape{ui}\selectfont upright italic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the file **texbook.tex**, and see this `\font\tenu=cmu10`. But I don't know what is the `mammac.tex` and why I need to download it?

Comment: @Y.zeng manmac is the macros used in the texbook, but you shouldn't need to download it, it is in texlive as /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/manmac.tex  also I showed the version using plain tex without using the manmac macros. (I removed the `^{..}` which is the manmac markup used to make the index in the texbook. so it works with plain tex)

Comment: There is another question, if we don't use `cmu` font, how can we get the upright italic font?

Comment: in plain tex there is no connection between fonts, cmu is not the italic version of cmr it's just another font. cmu is defined the same way as if you had defined times roman or whatever. So if you have an upright font simply load it with `\font`.  I have added a version for latex that would load the upright italic font version of any font if it is known (very few fonts have this) @Y.zeng

Comment: @Y.zeng Latin Modern also provides upright italic and `nfssext-cfr` provides commands to access fonts which have this shape in LaTeX. `cfr-lm` provides support for Latin Modern which is more complete than the standard `lmodern` package. (For upright italics, you could just use `nfssext-cfr` to get the font commands, but `cfr-lm` is a better option if you want Latin Modern generally.)

Answer (score 5):

Note this is a LaTeX answer following up on the discussion in comments on [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699825/).

`cfr-lm` provides `\textui{}` and `\uishape` for Latin Modern, which also includes this shape.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cfr-lm}


\begin{document}

Latin Modern also includes an \textui{upright italic} which is supported by \texttt{cfr-lm}.

{\itshape Some italic text of the regular sort, \upshape some upright and \uishape some upright italic.}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: upright italic Latin Modern]

Comment: May you tell me: 1) how to get the David's anwer's link as you did in your answer? 2) Is `lmodern` package is automatically loaded in LaTeX?

Comment: @Y.zeng (1) Click on 'share' beneath the post and remove the digits after the last forward slash if you don't want SE using links to track you. (2) No.

Comment: I learned much. Thanks a lot.